# Zorn's lemma implies the well-ordering principle on ZF

Tags: elementary-set-theory

*Theorem[ZF]*. Zorn's lemma implies the well-ordering principle.

**My question is**: Why the theorem says this on th ZF? Why not on the ZFC? Can you explain?

Answer (score 3):

On ZFC the well-ordering principle is true. So the statement "Zorn's lemma implies the well-ordering principle" is vacuously true.

Comment: Okey. So, can we use axiom of choice to prove the theorem on the ZFC?

Comment: In the system ZFC, Well ordering principle is implied by the axiom of choice which (is part of the foundations). So yes, you can prove the well ordering principle by the axiom of choice. And after than any statement of the form "$p \implies $ well ordering principle" is true (even if $p$ were a false statement in ZFC).